# Getting "site not found" error after deploying in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

getting site not found error in custom domain after deployed. But able to access firebase subdomain. Sub-domain is   good to access but issue is only with custom domain.

I need the deployed changes need to published in the custom domain also. the custom Domain is already connected successfully.

Comment: *"the custom Domain is already connected successfully."* i'm not sure what do you meant by this. is the app self-hosted on a third party hosting? can you elaborate the setup more?

Comment: hosted in firebase, bought domain from godaddy and connected with subdomain in firebase

Comment: *"connected with subdomain in firebase"* - is the subdomain accessible from your godaddy server? if you have access to it's bash/console terminal you can try to `ping` it.

Comment: example of subdomain in firebase [myjobs-xxyy.web.app]. After deploying the local code in firebase the site is accessed in the firebase sub domain but getting "site not found error " in the custom domain connected to this firebase sub domain.    Error message" Site Not Found
Why am I seeing this?
There are a few potential reasons:

You haven't deployed an app yet.
You may have deployed an empty directory.
This is a custom domain, but we haven't finished setting it up yet.
How can I deploy my first app?
Refer to our hosting documentation to get started."

Comment: so, it works using the subdomain but not the godaddy one? my bad, i thought you were hosting your files in godaddy. how did you setup your custom domain? did you double check [these steps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain)?